# How can I print numbers in python (2.7) in scientific notation with a fixed exponential power?

Tags: python, scientific-notation

I have several plots and I want the printed numbers in these plots to have the same exponential.

e.g. 1.41e-4, 0.85e-4, 0.05e-4

this format ".2e" 
does not give a standard exponential form.

Comment: using matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, using matplotlib.